# creating an xml file?

Tags: android, xml, file

I am trying to create an xml file in android but I get empty files. I have read many articles about this issue but I did not manage to find a solution. My mimeType is text/xml and this is my code for selecting directory

```
 private void createFile(String mimeType, String fileName) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType(mimeType);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
            startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and this is my code for passing data to my file.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {
        if (requestCode == WRITE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = resultData.getData();
            String fileData = "the data I want to write to file";
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
            try{
             fileOutputStream=(FileOutputStream) getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri); }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
            XmlSerializer serializer= Xml.newSerializer();
            StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();
            try {
                serializer.setOutput(writer);
                serializer.startDocument("UTF-8",true);
                serializer.startTag("","myTag");
                serializer.text(fileData);
                serializer.endTag("","myTag");
                serializer.endDocument();
                String val= writer.toString();
                fileOutputStream.write(val.getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Exception writing to " + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

the file is created but there is nothin in it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`fileOutputStream=(FileOutputStream) getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);` should be crashing with a `ClassCastException`. `openOutputStream()` returns an `OutputStream`, but it is not necessarily a `FileOutputStream`.

The stack trace for this exception should be showing up in LogCat.

Comment: I also tried this OutputStream fileOutputStream=getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

Comment: @IoannaDln: Call `flush()` and `close()` on the `OutputStream` after writing the bytes. Always log exceptions to LogCat, so you can see the stack trace -- do not rely on a `Toast` alone. Step through the code in a debugger to ensure that all of the statements are being executed that you expect.

Comment: flush() and close() did not change anything. Another empty xml file was created

Comment: @IoannaDln: How exactly are you determining that the file is empty? You might also want to switch to using `PrintWriter` instead of trying `getBytes()`. Also, step through the code in a debugger to ensure that all of the statements are being executed that you expect and that `val` contains your desired XML.

Comment: a file is created and there is nothing writen in it. An empty document. I am trying out PrintWriter to see if it works

Comment: @IoannaDln: "a file is created and there is nothing writen in it. An empty document." -- please explain **in detail** how you are determining this. Are you using `adb shell`? Are you using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio? Are you using an on-device file manager? Are you using some desktop OS file manager? Are you using something else?

Comment: I use windows file manager to read the file. I can't think of any other way to explain it. Not a single letter is in my .xml. It is blank

Comment: @IoannaDln: Try using `adb shell` or Device File Explorer in Android Studio 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't unerstand why but it seems to be a mobile device issue. My code works fine on other mobile devices. Thanks